# What is the thermal scattering cross section of a free electron?

Tags: thermal-radiation, scattering-cross-section

I wonder how much of thermal irradiance an electron picks up?

Can it be determined from [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) and [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_scattering#Compton_scattering)?

The cross section seems to vary with temperature.